# HTML video player not working when appending value from text field

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, video.js, web-development-server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Video</title>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.7.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    
    
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Live Streaming</h1>
   <input type="text">
   <button type="submit">
   JOIN
   </button>
   <video-js autoplay muted id="my_video_1" class="vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268">
    <source src="https://ap02.iqplay.tv:8082/iqb8002/3m9n/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
   </video-js>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
   <script src = "https://unpkg.com/browse/@videojs/http-streaming@1.13.3/dist/videojs-http-streaming.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    var player = videojs('my_video_1');
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to modify the following code that when user enter any url of live streaming video and click on join button so it should show that channel in video player.
I have tried with js but no luck.
Could anyone please share any thing which can be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Video</title>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.7.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    
    
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Live Streaming</h1>
   <input type="text">
   <button type="submit" onclick="loadVideo()">
   JOIN
   </button>
   <video-js autoplay muted id="my_video_1" class="vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268">
    <source src="" type="application/x-mpegURL">
   </video-js>
    <script>
    function loadVideo(){
    var player = videojs('my_video_1');
    player.src({
  src: document.querySelector('input').value,
  type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
});
}
   </script>
     <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.15.4/video.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I tested it by disabling cors policy of chrome and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

Use the player's `src` method to load a new video.

```js
player.src({
  src: document.querySelector('input').value,
  type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
});
```

NB you don't need to include the http-streaming script, as it is included in the video.js dist script.

Comment: if you have a fiddle link for it then it would be good because when i am leaving the source empty becuase i want to get it from input field so it's throwing error.

Comment: The mp4 videos are running perfectly fine but if the video is in m3u8 format then it's not getting play. :(